# DataGrid ItemsSource isn't displayed

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I hope someone can tell me the reason for this behaviour:

If I do the following:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Model.Bytes}" .../>
```

My ViewModel constructor:

```
public ViewModel()
{
    Model = new Message();
    Model.Bytes.Add(new Byte(){Range = "42"});
}
```

Nothing happens and the output window doesn't show any errors.

But If I wrap this Byte collection:

```
public ICollection<Byte> Bytes
{
    get { return Model.Bytes; }
    set
    {
        Model.Bytes = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(()=> Bytes);
    }
}
```

And write:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Bytes}".../>
```

The datagrid shows the entry and I can add new ones.

My Message-Class

```
public Message()
{
    Bytes = new ObservableCollection<Byte>();
}

public virtual ICollection<Byte> Bytes
{
    get { return GetValue(() => Bytes); }
    set { SetValue(() => Bytes, value); }
}
```

I think it is a notification problem, but I don't know where or why...

Thank you in advance

Comment: `ViewModel` should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` as well as `Bytes`. But since `Bytes` is a simple `ICollection` it doesn't. So you have to manually rise event after changing `Bytes` reference or content. Simply rise `PropertyChanged` after that line which adds data. I don't know what your `RaisePropertyChanged()` does (it looks strange to me).

Comment: Did you pass the ViewModel as  a dataContext to your View ??

Answer (score 0):

```
 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Model.Bytes}" .../>
```

this means your DataContext have to be an object with a PUBLIC property MODEL, and the type of this property must have a PUBLIC property Bytes. if this is the case, then it just seems to be a notification problem.

simply check your DataContext and Binding at runtime with Snoop.

Comment: hey blindmeis, my Model is 'public Message Model{get;set;}' and as you can see the class Message has an ObservableCollection<Byte> Bytes. Could it be possible that ItemsSource needs a direct binding to a collection instead of Model.Bytes?

Comment: no it should work. can you change your ICollection<Byte> to OberservableCollection<Byte>

Comment: Hey blindmeis, I have found my mistake: In the BaseViewModel was a method which set the Model to null... Thanks for your help and excue me, please :)